# Splitting cell in Excel

Tags: excel, split

I cut and paste a 4-column table into Excel, and it comes in as a single column. I need to split the data in each cell of this column into 4 separate cells. I have found various commands/pieces of code to split cells, but none that seem to help me out in this particular situation.

The data comes into each cell as a string:

a name (number and format of words can vary) and then a number (always 1-3 digits) and then another name as before and finally another number

For example, a cell might contain the following:

```
Smith, John 22 Jane Marie Johnson 3
```

What I want to do is split this into 4 separate cells, where `Smith, John`, `22`, `Jane Marie Johnson`, and `3` all get their own cell. Because the folks who enter the data are not careful, sometimes there are a different numbers of spaces between the pieces of the string that I want to chop up:

It might look like this:

```
Smith, John 22 Jane Marie Johnson 3
```

Or it might look like this:

```
Smith, John 22  Jane Marie Johnson 3
```

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: [This?](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/split-text-into-different-cells-HA102809804.aspx)

Comment: If I'm correct in interpreting your question you want to split into `Smith, John`, `22`, `Jane Marie Johnson` and `3` then the position of the 1st `2` in `22` is a critical bit of information.  Googling "position of first numeric in string" returns lots of useful hits - most using array formulas. If you don't mind using "helper cells" you may be able to devise 4 formula in 4 adjacent cells to display the string in 4 columns. If you don't want to use "helpers" then you will need 4 mega array formulas!

Comment: You need to do the research, try writing some formulas and then, if you run into problems, post what you have tried and where it doesn't work. I could provide an answer but that isn't how SO works - you have to demonstrate some effort to solve the problem first. **NB** I'm not one of the down-voters because I hope you will learn how to ask a good SO question.

Answer (score 0):

1. To split into cells use: [text to column feature](http://spreadsheets.about.com/od/Text-Functions/ss/2011-05-28-excel-2010-trim-function.htm)

   2.To remove unimportant spaces use the [trim function](http://spreadsheets.about.com/od/Text-Functions/ss/2011-05-28-excel-2010-trim-function.htm). Like: `TRIM(D1)`